# How to return translated text JavaScript google Translate API

Tags: javascript, api, async-await, promise, google-translate

I wrote the following code to translate from Arabic to English, I want the function to accept English as source and return the translated text,

can some one help me on this?

```
translateArtoEn(source) {
let url = `https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=${API_KEY}`;
url += '&q=' + encodeURI(source);
url += `&source=ar`;
url += `&target=en`;

console.log(url)

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json"
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data.translations[0]["translatedText"]
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log("There was an error with the translation request: ", error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided will not return any value since I assume the function is synchronous.

With this, you may use `callback` function to return the desired result after the parent function has already returned.

Please see below code for your reference:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function main(){
        var source = '<your_desired_text_to_translate>';
        translateArtoEn(source,myDisplayer);
}

function translateArtoEn(source,callback){
    var API_KEY = '<your_API_key>';
    let url = `https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=${API_KEY}`;
    url += '&q=' + encodeURI(source);
    url += `&source=ar`;
    url += `&target=en`;

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json"
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((response) => {
            callback(response.data.translations[0].translatedText)
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log("There was an error with the translation request: ", error);
    });
}

function myDisplayer(result) {
        // handle the result here
        console.log("Translated text: ",result);
}

if (require.main === module) {
  main();
}
```

In this code, `callback` is used to pass the returned value (after the execution of the parent function is finished) to another function that will handle the result.